# Session JSession Id in tomcat 5.5.27

Tags: tomcat

My tomcat was 5.5.27. Is it anyway to secure the jession id like add the secure="true" in tomcat 6.0?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you thinking of adding `secure="true"` in your configuration?

Comment: i add this to my connector setting in the server.xml

Answer (score 1):

`secure="true"` has no bearing on the "secure" attribute of a JSESSIONID cookie. If you want to set the "secure" flag in a JSESSIONID's cookie, then you'll have to make sure that the user's `HttpSession` is created during a request over HTTPS.